# Need PHP Function that converts sizes from byte to yottabyte and reverse

Tags: php, size, byte, calculator

some thing like that

```
function convert_size($from,$to,$unit){

some code...

return $calculated_value

}

echo convert_size("YB","KB",50);
```

- Byte (B)
- Kilobyte (KB)
- Megabyte (MB)
- Gigabyte (GB)
- Terabyte (TB)
- Petabyte (PB)
- Exabyte (EB)
- Zettabyte (ZB)
- Yottabyte (YB)

Comment: Ok. And what have you tried?

Comment: Here's something to compare your results with: [50 Yottabytes](http://www.lonniebest.com/DataUnitConverter/#50YB) = 50,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 kilobytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that:

```
function convert_size($from,$to,$unit){
  $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB');
  if(($fromPosition = array_search($from,$units)) === false){
     return false;
  }
  if(($toPosition = array_search($to,$units)) === false){
    return false;
  }
  $diffUnits = $fromPosition-$toPosition;
  return $unit * (pow(1024, $diffUnits));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for a more clean way to do this, use this function:

```
function convert_size($from, $to, $unit)
{
    $units = array(
        'B' => 1,
        'KB' => 1024,
        'MB' => 1024^2,
        'GB' => 1024^3,
        // fill with more units you need
    );

    return ($unit*$units[$from])/$units[$to];
}
```

for example to convert 3Gb to MB, the final formula should be `(3×(1024^3))÷(1024^2)`, and it will result in 3072MB.